# P5.js Visual (Syntax Loop issue)

Tags: javascript, loops, text, p5.js, web-testing

I was playing around with this bit of code as its a visual I may include as part of my university project (to introduce it) but there are 2 issues I have been unable to resolve:

I am happy with how it begins, however around 10seconds in (Project: One, Pink Slide) it goes white then 8second later resumes with a black slide (One Project:) right before the loop ends and then begins again.

I am hoping to get rid of the 8second delay as well and the final slide that continues on after the delay (One Project:, Black Slide)

I changed the rx and ry variables around on lines 38 and 39 as well as the syntax on line 31, 32, 41, 42 but to no avail, I am still unable to get rid of the delay as well as the last slide.

```
 var rectWidth = 1000;
 var rectHeight = 600;
 var colourlapse;
 var rx = 60;
 var ry = 60;
 var inc = 0.005;


let colors = [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [255, 9, 236]]
let cur_col1 = 1;
let cur_col2 = 0;

let textContents = ["Project:","2019","One"];

function setup() {
 frameRate(49);
 createCanvas(1100, 1100);
 colourlapse = 0.0;
 }

function draw() {
 var w = colourlapse * rectWidth;
 var sx1 = (inc > 0) ? rx : rx + rectWidth - w;
 var sx2 = (inc > 0) ? rx + w : rx;

  background(255);
  stroke(255);

  let index1 = cur_col1 % colors.length;
  let index2 = cur_col2 % colors.length;
   fill(colors[index2]);
   rect(sx1, ry, w, rectHeight);

  // text
  textSize(35);
  textStyle(BOLD);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  text(textContents[index1], 550, 320, sx2, ry);
  text(textContents[index2], 550, 350, sx2, ry);

  fill(colors[cur_col2 % colors.length]);
  rect(sx2, ry, rectWidth-w, rectHeight);

  colourlapse += inc;
    if (colourlapse >= 1) {
     colourlapse = 1;
     inc *= -1;
     cur_col2 += 2;
    } else if (colourlapse <= 0) {
     colourlapse = 0;
     inc *= -1;
     cur_col1 += 2;
     }
    }
```

Comment: You draw a whit text on a whit background, because one of the colors in white.

Comment: And for the delay, is there anything you can see that may be causing it?